# Twig output caching

Tags: php, caching, twig

I'm new to Twig and like it, but i've got one problem right now.
I can't find a proper solution for the caching of the output. I have some templates that need heavy database use and should better be cached for some minutes.

But i can't figure out a proper solution because i always did quick and dirty caching and want to find a clean solution now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig is only templating engine and do not provide a cache system like you want.

You need to cache the whole request (controller with heavy database queries + template rendering).

If you use [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org) the [HttpCacheServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/http_cache.html) is what you want.

If you use [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) or want to use the Symfony HttpKernel Component, [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html) can interest you

Comment: I think HttpCache is not for caching data from a database. You'd rather have a look at [*Doctrine Result cache*](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache).